# How do I remove map (I am using Mapbox API for map) from the natural tab flow in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, mapbox, tabindex

I am using Mapbox API to integrate a map on my web page. I want to skip the map content from the natural tab flow when I press tab keys.
I tried setting `tabindex="-1"` in the map container but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```js
/**
 * Initialize leaflet map, called from HTML.
 */
initMap = () => {
  self.newMap = L.map('map', {
    center: [40.722216, -73.987501],
    zoom: 12,
    scrollWheelZoom: false
  });
  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg70?access_token={mapboxToken}', {
    mapboxToken: 'My-api-key',
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
      '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
      'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
  }).addTo(newMap);

  updateRestaurants();
}
```

Comment: What does the generated html look like?  You can copy/paste from the code inspector of your browser.  Also, `tabindex` is not inherited so if you set it to -1 on a parent container, that will not prevent any children from being tabbed to.

Comment: This is a section of code taken from my project. When the HTML is generated, it shows a map on the top and list of restaurants below.

Comment: No, I'm talking about what the generated html looks like, not your original code.  You have to go into the code inspector for the browser and copy/paste the code from there.